# semanticoverflow.com - can't find it in "all Stack Exchange sites"

Tags: support, clone

I ran into this site: http://www.semanticoverflow.com/

But I can't find it on here: https://stackexchange.com/sites

Is it even an "official" Stack Exchange project?

Answer (score 10):

According to the headers

> `<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">`

it is a Stack Exchange 1.0 site. This service was discontinued and replaced with Area 51 and Stack Exchange 2.0, and since it doesn't have the Stack Exchange Multi Colider Thingy Me Bop<sup>TM</sup>, it is not an **official** Stack Exchange site, albeit running the older Stack Exchange software. For the site to become part of the Stack Exchange network, it will need to be added to Area 51 and follow the complete process.

Comment: +1 "I remember when all this was green fields, lad." Etc.

Comment: +1 for Thingy Me Bops...we need more of them.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is one of the early sites that was launched prior to the establishment of Stack Exchange, as it's definitely running an (albeit older) version of the software. From what I can recall, it was possible to pay for the hosting of a stack site for a while, and I'm guessing you're looking at an example of this.

It looks like it launched ~October, 2009, which would make sense in this context.

There's some launch blurb which looks like it's form one of the creators ([www.SemanticOverflow.com – the Web 2.0 Q&A site for all things Web 3.0.](http://aabs.wordpress.com/2009/10/27/www-semanticoverflow-com-the-web-2-0-qa-site-for-all-things-web-3-0/)) which also backs up this theory.

Comment: interesting. but why didnt it get integrated/updated? is the software publicliy available?

Comment: @Joe Hopfgartner I believe only the Stack Exchange sites are upgraded in this manner. As @Diago says in his answer, it would presumably need to go through the Area 51 process for it to become part of the modern Stack Exchange set up.